# Pronunciation of ויכולו in Friday night davening

Tags: tefilla

What is the accurate pronunciation of word ויכולו which we say in shul Friday night? I've encountered both "Vaychulu" and "Va-yichulu." I've been informed about a scholarly dispute (machlokes) regarding the use of sheva Na/Nach in this word, but I'm unsure about the specifics.

Comment: It should be “va-y’chulu”.

Comment: Artscroll instructions say Va-Yichulu

Comment: Is there something special about Friday night that would change the pronunciation, or would you happy for a pronunciation guide aimed at reading the Torah?

Comment: I hear different pronunciations when I'm in shul Friday night - this isn't specific to Friday night prayers. Any information on Hebrew pronunciation/grammar would be great!